# Use a trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2 to change the value of one column based on the value of another column during update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to change the value of a column when a record is updated, based on the value of another column in the same table.  The legacy application updating the table cannot be re-coded to handle this.

The basic logic would be:

- If `DateShipped` is not null, set `OrderLocation = 4`

Hoping I can do this at the database level with an update trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2.

thank you.

Comment: Read up on how to [Create Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). Also would you want this to happen before the update (`INSTEAD OF` trigger with an extra update call) or after? The triggers only allows you to define what will happen before/after the actual update.

Comment: Is this "`OrderLocation` must be 4 if `DateShipped` isn't `null`" or "*when* `DateShipped` transitions to being non-`null`, `OrderLocation` should be set to 4" - i.e. is it valid for `OrderLocation` to be changed to different values later? Does changing `DateShipped`, providing the new value isn't `null`, always reset `OrderLocation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_OrderLocation_Update
ON TableName 
FOR UPDATE,INSERT
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t
   SET t.OrderLocation = 4
  FROM TableName t INNER JOIN inserted i 
  ON t.PK_Column = i.PK_Column  --<-- what ever the primary key column
  WHERE i.DateShipped IS NOT NULL
END
```